# ONLY getting 404 error when C# / ASP.NET MVC app is online (IIS 8.5) when on Chrome

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have an app I created and posted on IIS and everything is running perfectly (on Internet Explorer only). When I go to google chrome I get random 404 errors. I only have 2 pages on the app so the thing is when I click one button to get to a different page it throws a 404 error (but only sometimes).

**Back story:** I open the app and everything works fine on Chrome. If I let it sit for a little over 1 minute, AND THEN try to click the button to go to the next page it will throw a 404 error. IF I used this app on Internet Explorer, ALL DAY LONG, I will never get a 404 error when trying to go to the other page. Even after letting it sit on my page for hours.

I have worked on finding the culprit for about 3 days now and have read every SO and .net forum that google could find. I just don't understand what is going on and reaching out in hopes someone has seen this exact thing.

I have troubleshooted everything i know and nothing shows in the dev tools. Except for the 404 error.

**404 error:** the page cannot be found and then it gives me the url which is 100% correct.

Why would this work 100% of the time in Internet Explorer, but not Chrome?

**EDIT:**
Here is an image of fiddler. After 2 minutes i get the 404 error but i am not seeing any useful info from fiddler?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le6io.png)

Comment: So you can take that url.. and paste it back into chrome and it works? or will never work again... what authentication and authorization is set up? is it possible to make a tiny reproducible demo in another app? if not, then you are on the way to solving your problem.

Comment: If you really want to find out use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  The default headers in c# are not the same as other applications.  So you need to add/modify headers for c# code to work.  Also the TLS version has to be correct for HTTPS modes to work.  The default version of TLS when you do not set version is a combination of the windows version and the net version. Many websites do not allow IE (or other browsers) so in c# you have to set the User Agent header to a browser the server accepts.  Then sometimes you can user one browser which sets a cookie and the a non working will work.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your comment. I will look into Fiddler. Never used it before so I will give that a shot.

Comment: You may need to set the User Agent in the header.  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: @jdweng I have edited my question with an image of fiddler. I dont really see anything too useful.

Comment: It's a shoot in the dark, but ... can be something related with Upgrade-Insegure-Request header? A minimal project shared at github would be helpfull.

Comment: @awquadros I will try to make a github for it but its just so weird. for some reason google chrome is timing out my application after 2 minutes. where IE works all day. Once google chrome times it out i have to reload my app in order to use it.

Comment: Compare the sniffer results between Chrome and IE to see if there is any differences.  I sound like a script or Java that is running on the page.  You may want to delete browser history.  You may have some spyware in your history that is causing issue.

Comment: Is your issue solved? If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue. If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members. If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it. We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

First, clear the chrome browser cache and history.make sure you have extensionless URL handler:

```
     <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" 
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/980368/a-update-is-available-that-enables-certain-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5-handlers

configure below setting in iis:

1)Open iis, select your site.

2)Double click on request Filtering

3)Filename Extensions Tab -> Edit Feature Settings -> check Allow unlisted file name extensions

set the below code in web.config file:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```